# Is there a 3D shape with a flat face throughout which one would experience constant "downward" acceleration?

Tags: calculus, geometry, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

[A spaceman restricted to the center of his platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4zbM.jpg)

A person standing on a thin disk in space will experience gravitational acceleration exactly normal to the surface only when he is situated exactly in the center. Is there a finitely large "underlayment" we can place underneath this platform such that if one were to walk on it one would experience a gravitational acceleration of constant magnitude and normal to the surface no matter where one is standing on it? What shape must this underlayment take, and can it be achieved using only material of uniform density?

[A spaceman and his companions experiencing the same acceleration at various points on the platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pecEx.jpg)

edit: [The cross sectional area of the underlayment can be larger than the platform.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRBRh.jpg)

edit: One way to approach this problem might be to first consider a "2D" version of the problem: a thin wafer with a flat edge may take any finite shape, with the goal being to have the gravitational acceleration perpendicular to the flat edge and of constant magnitude at all points along the edge. It may be the case that a solution to the 3D platform problem is simply a solid of revolution of the 2D solution.

Comment: Note that the gravitational force being normal everywhere in a connected region is equivalent to the gravitational potential being constant over that region.

Comment: Good point. That may prove useful as a way of framing the problem.

Comment: Well now, is the "underlayment" permitted to be larger in cross-section than the circular surface?  Could it be, for instance, a [right conical frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum)?

Comment: Yes it can be larger in cross-section than the flat surface.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath402/kmath402.htm

Comment: Do you mean that the gravitational force is exactly constant up to some finite distance above the platform (or only in the limit of infinitesimal spacemen)?

Comment: I'm not sure. When I originally thought about the problem, I only thought about limiting the size of the platform in absolute terms, but I didn't think about specifying the size of the platform with respect to the spacemen (which in retrospect is a lot more important!) For the sake of simplicity, let's go with "point particle" spacemen, or infinitesimal spacemen as you say.

Comment: @Rahul However, if the field is normal over a plane surface, it does not imply that the field strength is constant. See for example [The charged conducting disk](https://blog.richmond.edu/physicsbunn/2013/03/01/the-charged-conducting-disk-again/). (This might only be possible with a surface charge, which implies an infinite volume charge density.)

Comment: @Rahul Suppose the field is normal and constant over the flat (equipotential) surface. Consider the equivalent electrostatic problem. Take the continuation of the equipotential (which may not enclose all the charges) and replace it with a conductor with charge equal to the enclosed charge. A constant field (outside of the bounded volume containing charge) satisfies the boundary conditions on the flat surface. Is that unique?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the gravitational acceleration $\vec{g}$ is parallel to $\hat{z}$ in the Cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$.  If $\phi$ is the gravitational potential, then $\vec{g}=-\vec{\nabla}\phi$ implies that $\phi$ must be independent of $x$ and $y$ (as $-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$ and $-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$ are the $x$- and $y$-components of $\vec{g}$, which are $0$).  Hence, since the mass density $\rho$ is governed by Poisson's equation
$$\rho=\frac{\nabla^2\phi}{4\pi G}\,,$$
where $G$ is the gravitational constant, we conclude that $\rho$ does not depend on $x$ and $y$.  The conclusion is that it is impossible to construct such a flat surface so that $\vec{g}$ is always perpendicular to the surface, as it would require constant surface density.

Comment: $\phi$ must be independent of $x$ and $y$ only on the disk, not everywhere else. I don't see how you can conclude anything about $\rho$ since you don't know $\partial^2\phi/\partial z^2$, nor $\phi$ away from the disk.

Comment: The point is a finite flat surface with constant surface density cannot produce gravitational acceleration normal to the disk.  You can solve the equation $\rho=\frac{\nabla^2\phi}{4\pi G}$ near the boundary of the flat surface.  At the boundary, $\rho$ changes in some direction along the $(x,y)$-plane.  This will introduce a non-normal component in $\vec{g}$ at the boundary.  And by continuity, near the boundary, $\vec{g}$ is also non-normal to the flat surface.

Comment: But the question is not about the gravitational acceleration due to a finite flat surface alone, but due to a finite volume underneath it. Unless I misunderstand your comment, you seem to be answering the question "Does a disk produce gravitational acceleration purely normal to it?" which is not what was asked.

Comment: I showed that there can be no change in $\rho$ in the $x$- or $y$-direction, for $\vec{g}$ to be normal to a flat surface.  Even if there is a volume underneath the surface, my answer still covers that.  Since the OP wants a finite volume, the flat surface has a boundary, and near the boundary, it is impossible to have gravitational field perpendicular to the surface, because $\rho$ starts to be dependent of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: OK, I still don't follow your argument (how can you solve $\rho\propto\nabla^2\phi$ for $\rho$ if you don't know $\partial^2\phi/\partial z^2$?), but I am evidently misunderstanding everything you are saying, so I'll stop bothering you. Cheers,

Comment: No, you are not bothering me.  The point is there is no need to worry about how $\phi$ is dependent of $z$.  The important thing is that $\phi$, and also $\rho$, cannot be dependent of $x$ and $y$.  If you have an infinite flat surface, this would be possible.  However, if your flat surface is finite, there is no way to circumvent the boundary problem.